# How to get a field third party settings for every content entity forms

Tags: 8, entities, forms

Can someone explain or post an example of how to get a third party field settings on every content entity forms?

I'm looking for a generic code where a form can be customized (like calling a custom validator) if any field present in that form is having the third party settings that I have defined.

It could be a node form, a block form, a paragraph etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `hook_field_widget_form_alter()` to alter form elements of any content entity form.

For example how to add a validate callback when you have third party settings stored in the field configuration:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  $field_definition = $context['items']->getFieldDefinition();
  if ($field_definition instanceof \Drupal\field\FieldConfigInterface) {
    $mymodule_settings = $field_definition->getThirdPartySettings('mymodule');
    if (!empty($mymodule_settings)) {
      $element['#mymodule_settings'] = $mymodule_settings;
      $element['#element_validate'][] = 'mymodule_element_validate';
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @4k4 , is there a way to pass my third party settings values to the `#element_validate` function?

Comment: You can store it in $element. See the edited code.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the quick response @4k4. You Rock!